# How to configure VS Code to point to the Java source code from window's JDK installation?

Tags: java, windows, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

While editing my Java code, I am not getting the Javadocs from JDK's source code whenever I hover an element or do a [`<CTRL>+<LEFT CLICK>`](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/_Cb4VGgCESEA/SoEPt_O5XoI/AAAAAAAAUtw/7gi_6oRhwr4/s1600-h/File-1.png). Instead, I am getting code generated by a disassembler.

```
// Failed to get sources. Instead, stub sources have been generated by the disassembler.
// Implementation of methods is unavailable.
```

[image: auto-generated code by disassembler]

I know that IntelliJ gets the source code from:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1\lib\src.zip"
```

But in the case of VS Code, I don't know how to make it point to the appropriate place.
To work with java in VS Code I installed the [Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack).

Some installed extensions with the following IDs:

- vscjava.vscode-java-pack
- vscjava.vscode-java-dependency
- vscjava.vscode-maven
- redhat.java
- vscjava.vscode-java-debug
- vscjava.vscode-java-test

**What configuration or plugin am I missing?**

Comment: You can report to the authors or check if anyone posted it already, https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues

Comment: Thank you @LexLi. I moved a few configs, restarted, and eventually, I gave up. Later, out of nowhere, the issue was gone. Don't know what happened or how to reproduce it